# F5 Load balancer config to send JMS messages to every server in cluster

Tags: jms, weblogic, cluster-computing, f5

Our Project needs to send clear cache JMS message to clear the cache.

Problem is that the prod setup includes Weblogic servers in a cluster and we want the clear cache JMS message to be send to every server so that every server can clear its cache.

At the moment, the F5 load balancer just sends this clear cache JMS message to one of the server, only whose cache is cleared. We need to clear cache in every server in the cluster.

Can F5 be configured to send a particular type of JMS message (header and other XML tags can be identified for this JMS Clear cache message which is in xml format.) TO every server in the cluster?

Or is there any other solution?  Thanks

Dean

Answer (score 1):

- F5 iRules can be used for filtering the JMS messages
- To send to every server in the cluster "Clone Pool" feature can be used